# How to Pass html:text value with html:link in struts 1.2

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, struts, struts-1

My jsp page display a list using logic iterate. every row displayed has a edit link too. when edit linked clicked Name will be changed to textbox so it can be edited.and sent along with commit link.  html:text value i need to send  with html:link.
part of my jsp is below,where I have

html:text  property="newId"  value="<%=modId%>"/> I want to pass this property as hashmap with html link as I am sending     "/> as param1   Please help. or suggest any other way to do this. Thanks .

```
####################################################################################
<logic:equal name="mode" value ="1">
 <td><bean:write name="display" property="productId"/></td>
<logic:notEqual name="edit" value="1">          
<td><bean:write name="display" property="productName" /></td>       
</logic:notEqual>
<logic:equal name="edit" value ="1">
<logic:equal name="display" property="productName" value ="<%=modId%>">
<td><html:text  property="newId"  value="<%=modId%>"/></td>
</logic:equal>
 <logic:notEqual name="display" property="productName" value ="<%=modId%>">
<td><bean:write name="display" property="productName" /></td>   
</logic:notEqual>
</logic:equal>

<bean:define id="param1" name="display" property="productName"/>
<%
    String changedName=request.getParameter("changedName");
    System.out.println("  st: " + changedName);
    java.util.HashMap params = new java.util.HashMap();
    if(param1!=null)
        params.put("objectToEdit", param1);
        params.put("abc",param1);
        pageContext.setAttribute("paramsName", params);
%>
</logic:equal> 

#####################################################################################

Same JSP HTML:LINK PArt
 #######################################
<html:link action="Manager?edit=1" name="paramsName" onclick="return modify()">
 <logic:equal name="edit" value ="1">
   <logic:equal name="display" property="productName" value ="<%=modId%>">
    <img src="../images/commit.png" border="0" style="background-color:blue" title=" bean:message key="commit.data"/>" >
   </logic:equal>
</logic:equal>
</html:link>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I did it using java script.
hope my solution help someone

```
function modify(){
    var textBox = document.getElementById('editableTextBox');//text box name
    var newName = document.getElementById('editableTextBox').value;
    if(textBox!=null){
        var table = document.getElementsByTagName("table");
        var rows = table[3].rows;
        var rowCount=0;
        for(i=1;i<rows.length;i++){
            rowCount = i;
            var cells = rows[i].cells;

                     if(cells[1].hasChildNodes()){
           var nodeName = cells[1].childNodes[0].nodeName;
          if(nodeName=="INPUT"){
            break;
           }
        }
    }
    var reqCell =rows[rowCount].cells[cells.length-2];
    var oldLink = reqCell.childNodes[1].getAttribute("href"); //getOld link
    reqCell.childNodes[1].setAttribute("href",oldLink+"&newName="+newName)  //set href with appending text box value
}
}
```